# Benefit of using get before a method in react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I usually found that some people use `get` before the method in React classes `get instructions() {` but I didn't find anything related to this in React Docs nor in [MDN class Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). Is it performant or it serve some other purpose.

**Sample Code -**

```
class SomeComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  get instructions() {
    if (this.props.do) {
      return 'Click the button: ';
    }
    return 'Do NOT click the button: ';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.instructions}
        <Button onClick={() => alert('!')} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: And from the page you link to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods